# asio : multiple pending async_read?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

async_read calls the callback when the requested amount of bytes have been received. This may imply multiple calls to async_read_some.

In the documentation it is specified that there can be at most one pending async_read_some. The callback has to be called before the next async_read_some may be issued.

What about the async_read ? Can multiple async_read be queued ? If yes, is the order of execution guaranteed to be preserved ?

Comment: `async_read` is a free function so it can be called multiple times to read data from different streams, NOT multiple times for the same stream. 'async_read_some` is a member function of a socket/stream which is why there can only be one pending `async_read_some`. I'm sure that someone with a better understanding of the inner workings of `asio` than me can explain precisely why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`async_read(...)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html)

> This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the stream's `async_read_some` function, and is known as a composed operation. The program must ensure that the stream performs no other read operations (such as `async_read`, the stream's `async_read_some` function, or any other composed operations that perform reads) until this operation completes.

That would imply that you can't start any further `async_read` operations on the same stream until the completion handler (the callback) is called -- this should be only once, when the provided buffer is filled, completion condition is satisfied, or some error occurs.

You're not entirely clear on what you mean by "queueing" multiple `async_read` operations. The way you would implement a sequence of `async_read` operations would be by starting the next operation in the completion handler.

Comment: Thanks. This answers my question. I meant calling async_read multiple times in the same handler for instance.